# Update using cte in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table as follows:

```
create table temp_cte1(id int primary key,name nvarchar(max))
```

And another table as follows:

```
create table temo_cte2(id int,name nvarchar(max)),constraint fk_id foreign key(id) references temp_cte1(id)
```

Let us say I have the following values in both table:

```
insert into temp_cte1 values(1,'Vinay'),(2,'Afzal'),(3,'Yogesh'),(4,'Shashank')

insert into temp_cte2 values(1,'Arya'),(2,'Hussain'),(3,'Kwatra'),(4,'Sharma')
```

Now, as long as I use the cte to update the 'name' column of any table, it works fine.
But when I am trying to update the id, i am getting an error as the foreign key has been violated.

Query that is working fine:

```
with cte(id,FirstName,LastName) as(select t1.id,t1.name FirstName,t2.name LastName from temp_cte1 t1 inner join temp_cte2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id)
update cte set LastName='Arya' where id=1
```

But what I need.. to do is something like this:

```
with cte(id,FirstName,LastName) as(select t1.id,t1.name FirstName,t2.name LastName from temp_cte1 t1 inner join temp_cte2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id)
update cte set id=1222 where FirstName='Vinay'
```

Any help with this??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask _why_ you need to update the primary key? It sounds like a less good idea, _especially_ with foreign keys referencing it.

Comment: whatever the idea might sound, the problem is that seniors at my office wants this.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2499328/477878) handles that case, however I can't stress enough that _changing primary keys is a very bad idea_.

Comment: okay so is there an option that when i am trying to change the foreign key say id column the primary key gets changed.????

Comment: I sincerely doubt there is since it's not meant to be changed, but the only thing I can say for sure is that there is no way that I know of.

Comment: Okay, I guess I have what I needed.

First, I set the insert update specification of the temp_cte1 table as "Cascade" on update.

Then when I use the following query, i get what I need

    With cte as(select t1.id,t1.name FirstName,t2.name LastName from temp_cte1 t1 inner join temp_cte2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id)
    update t1 set t1.id=1222
    from temp_cte1 t1 inner join cte on t1.id=cte.id
    where cte.FirstName='Vinay'

The query is working fine for me. Thanks for your response. And pardon me in case i wasted your precious time.

Comment: if you are going for "Cascade" on update a simple update query will do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that should work for you:

```
ALTER TABLE temp_cte2 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

;with cte(id,FirstName,LastName) as(select t1.id,t1.name FirstName,t2.name LastName from temp_cte1 t1 inner join temp_cte2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id)
update cte set id=12232 where FirstName='Yogesh'

ALTER TABLE temp_cte2 CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

[How can foreign key constraints be temporarily disabled using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql)