# PostgreSQL: Update primary key, avoid conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I want to update the primary key in several rows of a table. If all rows were updated, the key would be unique again, but the update of the first row results in a temporary conflict with the key of the second row. Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Example:

```
create table erichtest ( i integer, v varchar(200) );
alter table erichtest add constraint pk_erichtest primary key(i);
insert into erichtest values(1, 'Eins');
insert into erichtest values(2, 'Zwei');
update erichtest set i=i+1;
```

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_erichtest"

Comment: `DEFERRED` is the term here.

Comment: Maybe dump and import the table. But why update primary key? It should not relate directly to the record.

Comment: @kometen: In my case, it's a small table and the user can rearrange the order in which the items in this table appear. If the user moves the third item to the first position, the actual `update` statement goes like this: `update foobar set i=case when i=3 then 1 else i+1 end where i between 1 and 3`. Maybe `i` is not a good choice for the primary key, but in Oracle this worked as expected... and since we use Slony-I for replication, we need a primary key.

Comment: I see. Maybe this thread is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499246/how-to-update-primary-key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Something like this should help](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html):

```
b=# begin;
BEGIN
b=# alter table erichtest drop constraint pk_erichtest ;
ALTER TABLE
b=#  alter table erichtest add constraint pk_erichtest primary key (i) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
ALTER TABLE
b=# set constraints pk_erichtest deferred ;
SET CONSTRAINTS
b=# update erichtest set i=i+1;
UPDATE 2
b=# select * from erichtest ;
 i |  v
---+------
 2 | Eins
 3 | Zwei
(2 rows)

b=# end;
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 10 subtract 9:

```
update erichtest set i=i+10;
update erichtest set i=i-9;
```