# how to update primary key value in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, primary-key

I have a country table which have a column **Countryid** I accidently deleted the CountryId Which Had value=1 and now in state table there is a value of column countryId=1 which is used to fetch the records (states) according to country id.
I had inserted the country again but it has different id
so how can I update the value again in country table of CountryId which  primary key from 2 to

Comment: Simply UPDATE the state table's Countryid column to 2 where it is 1.

Comment: but I have thousands of in others table too in state table which have the countryid=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499246/how-to-update-primary-key)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to use `set identity_insert off`.  The best place to start is with the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx).

More important, there is a very simple way to avoid these problems in the future:  use explicitly declared foreign key relationships.  If you had a foreign key constraint:

```
alter table state
    add constraint fk_state_country foreign key (countryId) references country(countryId);
```

Then the `delete` would not have been allowed.