# How to get deleted ID (primary key) and regenerate for new user?

Tags: database, laravel

I'm using Laravel 7.

I want to regenerate the deleted primary key ID.
For example, my database ids are:

```
================
id   | username|
================
1    |  john   |
2    |  abc    |
3    |  xyz    |
```

If any user deletes account like ID 2,
my database look like follows:

```
================
id   | username|
================
1    |  john   |
3    |  xyz    |
```

so, I want to get the gap ID, and create new user like with that ID.

```
================
id   | username|
================
1    |  john   |
2    |  mno    |
3    |  xyz    |
```

Comment: put the type of database you are using. ex: MYSQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL,...

Comment: Why you want to regenerate the deleted primary key ID?

Comment: Just dont. Stick to autoincremented ids. Reusing deleted ids causes more harm than good

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Manually using a unique id

you can `ALTER` the table you have so that:
**id** column is a **VARCHAR(13)** and removing **AUTO_INCREMENT**, manually adding unique ids ex: `<?php $id = uniqid(); ?>` which generates a unique id using the timestamp, ex: `output: (string) 60cc324a512d6`

### Manually using a unique id which is hashed with md5 hasing algorithm

if you want more uniqueness use `<?php $uniqueId= md5(uniqid()); ?>` which generates a unique id using the timestamp and then hasing it using md5() hashing function ex: `output: (string) f71d3e810cdcc8008429d31d3a6459d4` , and then alter the table to be **id** -> **VARCHAR(32)** and removing **AUTO_INCREMENT**

### Ok what to use?

Using the normal **AUTO_INCREMENT** is best even if you have ocd like me and want to fill those deleted ids, but it is up to you to use any.
md5 hasing algorithm will generate a harder to guess id, and is more safe, since uniqid() function uses timestamp to generate that id it can be guessed via hackers by generating ids using timestamps, even though slower but safer to use a string of 32 character as an id, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd want to change the user an ID is pointing to. The point of an ID is that it is unique. I would not recommend changing the user of an ID.

I recommend that you refer to this question:
[How to update primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499246/how-to-update-primary-key)

Comment: I don't want to change the ID. I want regenerate non-existence IDs or deleted ids. suppose my primary key have 2 digit unique id... So I can insert records or users(for example) to 01 to 99..
if few ids or records are deleted from middle... (like 33,54,61,....),
it will be able to used for user id of new records or users...its  save my ids...
either I have to create new ids with three digits values... 
is it possible to do something like that ?
Thanks...