# how to change primary key column to auto increment when its a foreign key of different table in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Can not alter table because animal id is foreign key in different table

```
 ALTER TABLE 'animal' CHANGE 'animal_id' 'animal_id' INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

Because I can't see your full code, however, I think you can try this:

```
ALTER TABLE 'animal' MODIFY 'animal_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Thank you leo but i tried this way but because of foreign key constraint it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something similar to this response: [How to update primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499246/how-to-update-primary-key). When you update the PK, I think you could do something like this response: [Alter a MySQL column to be AUTO_INCREMENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169080/alter-a-mysql-column-to-be-auto-increment).

But since this response is not best practice, if you don't need the data in the table, you could drop and then recreate the table.